# F# - Getting fst element of tuple from option type function

Tags: f#, tuples, option-type

I am trying to access the fst element of a tuple. Normally I use fst (tuple), but this situation is a little different.

```
let getCard (pl : player) : (card * player) option =
    let plDeck = pl 
    match plDeck with
    | c1::re -> Some (c1,(re)) 
    | [] -> None
```

This is my f# code. the player type is a list of `ints`, and the output is tuple with the first `int` of the player list, and the player list minus the first `int`.

It's an assignment from my computer science class, so it is required that I use the option type.

I am trying to access the `fst` element of the tuple in another function by writing

```
let gc = fst (getCard [1,2,3])
```

but it seems like I can't do it this way, since I am getting the warning:

> This expression was expected to have type
> ''a * 'b'     but here has type
> '(card * player) option'

How do I work around this?

Comment: `getCard` returns an option, `fst` receives a tuple, so you cannot pass the returned value of `getCard` to `fst`. Consider to make `gc` be an option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you're trying to access an option of tuple card * player while the function fst expects a tuple of card * player.

You could pattern match on your getCard function and extract the card.

```ml
let result = 
    match getCard [1..5] with
    | Some card -> fst(card)
    | None -> -1
```

You could also use pattern matching to extract the first part of your tuple.

```ml
let result = 
    match getCard [1..5] with
    | Some (card, _) -> card
    | None -> -1
```

As suggested by @Guran you shouldn't return magic numbers

```ml
let result = 
    match getCard [1..5] with
    | Some (card, _) -> Some card
    | None -> None
```

Comment: Using a "magic value" like -1 is bad form though. Much better to use an Option as return value here as well. ie `Some card`resp `None`

Comment: true I made an assumption that op just wanted the value

Comment: Perhaps. But given that this was an assignment with the purpose of introducing the option type, it would certainly be fitting to use it for the end result as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great solution!